# UITableview not expanding with auotlayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, autolayout, xib

I have designed xib with 3.5inch and placed one `UITableview`. While running in 3.5 its coming in the same size,but in 4 inch `UITableview` is not expanding.I have tried with changing the `TableView` height dynamically according to the content size.

```
CGRect frame = self.myTableview.frame;
frame.size.height = self.myTableview.contentSize.height;
self.myTableview.frame = frame;
```

Above code is not working for me .

Comment: In case of auto layout the frame changes will not work. Add a layout constraints to the tableview and bottom and upper sides of parent view

Comment: @nerowolfe:you mean to pin the tableview with top space and bottom space ?

Comment: Pin, or ctrl drag from tableview to top and bottom of view to set the values

Comment: dragging doesn't works,because i have other elements on the bottom and  top.

Comment: @nerowolfe: ihave pinned it,its working.But is this the right way ?

Comment: Drag to this elements and set relative positioning. Anyway, the frame changing in code will not work, so you need to find a working combination in IB

Comment: Sure, it is a right way.

Comment: @nerowolfe:Thanks Buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually its pretty simple with AutoLayout, Just remove all your dynamic sizings and PIN all the four sides with SuperView, clean and run now it'll do your need.